# Где найти базу правил дорожного движения?

Tags: веб-программирование, база-данных

Привет! Где-нибудь можно найти готовую базу правил дорожного движения, которую можно подключить к веб-приложению?

Если нет, то какими путями его можно создать?

Comment: купить в киоске книжку? Но правила для какой страны Вам нужны? Для Украины можно найти здесь - gai.org.ua. А перевести в нужную базу даных - это на пару часов работы.

Answer (score 2):

Распарсить с [викитеки](http://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%A4%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8) например (думаю там есть ПДД большинства стран, разумеется в соответствующих языковых разделах). wiki-разметку парсить не трудно.

Comment: можете поподробней рассказать как парсить,просто с этим я еще никогда не сталкивался